# Update a bar chart with a select one menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bar-chart

I want to display a bar chart according to the item i have selectionned.

```
<h:outputText value="Document: " />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{chartBean.document}" converter="#{documentConverter}" required="true">
     <f:selectItems value="#{chartBean.listSelectItemDocument}"/>
     <p:ajax event="change" update="barChart" immediate="true"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>  

<p:barChart id="barChart" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}"  
    title="Interactive Bar Chart" style="height:300px" min="0" >  
 <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{chartBean.itemSelectBar}" update="growl" />  
</p:barChart>
```

I work with primeface library.

```
public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
    createCategoryModel();
    return categoryModel;  
}


private void createCategoryModel() {  
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();
    ChartSeries dled = new ChartSeries();
    if(mDocument!=null)
    {
        dled.setLabel("Dled");
        List<Date> listDate = mUserDocumentManger.listDate(mDocument);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        for(Date lDate : listDate)
        {
            calendar.setTime(lDate);
            dled.set(date,number);
        }   
        categoryModel.addSeries(dled);
      }
    }
```

When I choose another item of the list, nothing happened ...
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Why you set immediate="true" ?

Comment: i dont know , i tried so many thing, even if i take away this tag, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you have any exceptions ?

Comment: nothing, the list doesnt go in the setDocument ..

Comment: I have just tested, i think your converter may have a mistake, please provide your converter and Document type.

Comment: I checked my converter with a workmate and the problem come from my object, i doesnt know that the equal was not falcultative.

Comment: Becareful to use equal() method.

Comment: What do you mean by "be careful" ?

Comment: I mean equal() method compare instance, not value, so i say that, have you finished you issue ? :)

Comment: Yes, the method equal solve the problem :)
I don't know where i'am supposed the put "Answered" in my post"

Comment: You post new answer and then mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helps

The solution is to create an equal method in my class Document